# JSON.serialize is mucking with my datetime objects. How do I fix this?

Tags: apex, unit-test, datetime, json, timezone

I feel that the following assertion should be true, but it is not:

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.now();
System.assertEquals('"' + testDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'' + '"'), JSON.serialize(testDate));
```

I get the following error:

> 16:38:28.966 (2966802000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: "2014-04-03T04:38:27.988Z", Actual: "2014-04-03T20:38:27.988Z"

**Update**: when using formatGMT I still get the error:

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.now();
System.assertEquals('"' + testDate.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'' + '"'), JSON.serialize(testDate));
```

> 16:51:32.228 (2228010000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: "2014-04-03T08:51:31.274Z", Actual: "2014-04-03T20:51:31.274Z"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the time wasn't in the correct format

> DateTime testDate = DateTime.now();
>   System.assertEquals('"' + testDate.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'**HH**:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'' + '"'), JSON.serialize(testDate));

Comment: Yes. that was it (facepalm).
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
hh == 12 hour hours.
HH == 24 hour hours.

Comment: sometimes another pair of eyes helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime.format()` method converts the value to the time zone of the user who is running the test. The serializer is displaying the value as GMT.

A simple solution would be to use the `DateTime.formatGMT()` method in your test.

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.now();
System.assertEquals('"' + testDate.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'' + '"'), JSON.serialize(testDate));
```

Update: (The problem is in the format string as noted by @melmoussaoui - 'HH' vs 'hh')

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.now();
String expectedValue = '"' + testDate.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'' + '"');
String actualValue = JSON.serialize(testDate);
system.debug('Expected: ' + expectedValue);
system.debug('Actual:   ' + actualValue);
System.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
```

Debug output:

```
14:12:04:046 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|Expected: "2014-04-03T21:12:04.853Z"
14:12:04:046 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|Actual:   "2014-04-03T21:12:04.853Z"
```

[Salesforce DateTime methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Comment: I'm still getting an error. Does your code snippet work for you?

Comment: @edgartheunready I've updated the answer and provided the debug output from my testing.