# Formatting Datetime.now()

Tags: apex, datetime, formatting

I need to format my Datetime.now() to be accepted for a SOAP request.

I can't seem to find a way to format it online. Can anyone advise? I need it to look like: `2019-05-02T21:20:29.999Z`

Currently I have tried: `.format()`, `.formatLong()`, 
`Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')` which I believe is the correct way, but this displays like so: `2019-05-03T16:45:18.646-0400`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track that you need to pass in a specific format string to `Datetime.now().format(...)`. Notice how you escape the `T` in your current format:

```
Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')
```

Just do the same thing with the `Z`:

```
Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'')
```

Note that `Z` is a valid argument in [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component    Presentation         Examples 
> ...       ...                       ...                  ...
> Z         Time zone                 RFC 822 time zone    -0800
> ```

See also:

- [DateTime.Format() Documentation example causes exception](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/114351/2995)
- [JSON.serialize is mucking with my datetime objects. How do I fix this?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/31816/2995)
- [Salesforce Apex: ISO Timestamp Format Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18550709/1492485)

Comment: ah I forgot to escape the Z. Thank you, you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
String s = JSON.serialize(Datetime.now()).replace('"','');
```

or

```
String s = JSON.serialize(Datetime.now()).substringBetween('"');
```

Comment: That approach is covered in the links I included, but I didn't add it here because it performs much worse. That said, this Q&A thread is probably more complete having it represented here.

Comment: True.  I added it because it is a convenient way to generate ISO datetimes without having to know the syntax of the ISO format.  And system integrations generally use ISO formats to transfer datetimes.  @AdrianLarson